# Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null on marshmallow

Tags: android

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
 DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());    
 os.writeBytes("adb shell pm grant " +getPackageName() + "        
 android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS \n");    
 os.writeBytes("exit\n");    
 os.flush();
```

Unable to execute the above code on Android M(API Level 23). Getting in logcat:

> Error running exec(). Command: [su]  Working Directory: null Environment: null on marshmallow

The above code works well on API Level <= 22(L) devices. However it's not working on Android M.